# .net Arrays and sequentiality - clarification?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

.Net arrays elements are stored in a sequential memory cells.Even the so called "dynamic" `List<T>` uses an Array behind the scenes - where each addition of elements - [make sure that an appropriate array is created](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#134). ( unless inistantiated with a pre defined capacity)

**Question**

*Why* it was written like that?

Seeking every time (when size exceeds) -  a new sequential region  - can be a big performance hit.

They could also used another approach which is -  `n % m` regions of sequential cells . - so we benefit  **both**  seek performance AND not needing to search for 100% sequential free cells."

*(was the designers counted on the fact that the GC will compact/defrag memory so it will always be easy for them to find sequential free cells ? )*

Comment: This question is best put to ScottGu. No one else can tell you the real reason :-).

Comment: @SujaySarma All i'm saying that seeking 100% sequential cells for implementing an array - raises some questions . And i'll be happy to learn from the answers.

Comment: Well, it is a language. You cannot write a language that is optimized for one particular scenario. Something that may be beneficial to one scenario may actually hurt badly somewhere else. That is probably why they decided to keep it simple.

Comment: When a List<> is crerated with a Capacity then that's just the _initial_ size. The behaviour does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They could also used another approach which is - n % m regions of sequential cells . - so we benefit both seek performance AND not needing to search for 100% sequential free cells."

There is no need to "search for 100% sequential free cells.". Allocation is very fast in .NET.

The real cost is in copying the contents of the old to the new array. And you are right, a mxn structure could reduce some of that cost.

But there's always a trade-off, while the worst-case for Add() would improve the costs for Insert(), Remove() and especially Seek()  (`this[int x]` ) would increase.